# Extract 10 Numbers from a long string

Tags: c#

I am in a pinch. I am reading a non-delimited text file and have been successful except for one detail: I need to identify a 10 digit number inside a string line that is a employee identifier and link it to a database to extract the email and email the employee that file. I have no problems extracting the file (which is one massive text file with all employees's data in there) individually per employee, but I need to e-mail them this individual file. Now, I have a query, that while not optimized at all won't cause problems in operation because its a secondary database and barely used.

```
 using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            cnn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  EMail from Stubs WHERE CONTAINS (ID, @ID)", cnn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", (line));
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (rdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {
   email = rdr.GetString(0);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I am checking every read line and comparing it to a field. Obviously this won't work because the string always consist of this:

```
Acct              0100001170                              180.18   39,870.80
```

I need to extract those 10 digits there, 0100001170, and use that extracted value to identify a column in the DB and get the E-Mail address.

How can I only extract that number? is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried a regular expression?

Comment: [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/) supports reading fixed-width text files. It should be possible to use that to extract the data required.

Comment: Well that makes too much sense. Hmm... I have no idea on how to build a Regex like that though.

Comment: `string digits = Regex.Match(str, @"\d+").Value;`

Comment: Split it on spaces and then grab the second element? Seems easier than a regex if that's not your thing.

Comment: Will try the regex. The text file is massive, so it has multiple lines per file which is why I I am just grabbing the whole line. Will check regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon Skeet suggested, a regular expression will work for this scenario.

```
    string id = Regex.Match(line, @"(?<=\s)\d{10}(?=\s)").Value;
```

What this does is capture a certain part of your input string (`line` in this case) based on a search pattern. The one I built here, `"(?<=\s)\d{10}(?=\s)`" comprises of a few confusing-looking elements.

- **(?<=\s)** - This is a positive lookbehind for `\s`, the whitespace character. This will match anything that has whitespace *before* the string
- **\d** - This matches a digit
- **{10}** - This says to match the *preceeding* token (`\d` in this case) 10 times.
- **(?=\s)** - Similar to the first item this looks for whitespace *after* the string

After the Regex match, you should have a string containing ten numeric digits which is accessed with `.Value`.

If you find yourself struggling with regular expressions in the future, I recommend [Regexr](http://regexr.com?376q0). It is a web application that allows you to test out regex strings and matching and gives quite good reference for the different tokens.

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. I put up a messagebox to see if it displayed the number correctly and it did, the main problem I am having in my logic is that  since the variable will be constantly refreshing (with every line) it "wipes out" the variable. Since this worked I will look into seeing how to work with the code I have

Comment: Worked around with the limitation I had with a small if/else logic. Thanks FLG

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the Account Number is in the same position in each line:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    email = rdr.GetString(0);
    // make sure the string is long enough or you will get an index out of range exception
    if (rdr.GetString().Length() > 29)
    {
        string acctno = rdr.GetString().Substring(19, 10);
        // do something with acctno, maybe cast it to an Int64 if it is numeric
    }
}
```